# Why does the server return MIME type of 'text/html' when I import React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my js:

```
import React from './node_modules/react';
import ReactDOM from './node_modules/react-dom';

let thePage = React.createElement(
  'main',
  null,
  'lol'
);

ReactDOM.render(thePage, document.getElementById('app'));
```

But when I open its associated HTML page in my browser, I get this error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Here's what my React folder looks like for reference:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aPfd.png)

Oh and the html and js files are in the 'my-app' folder.

It occurred to me that there doesn't seem to be a "react.js" or any such file, but I've tried reinstalling it and that's always what it comes out as, so I don't know if that's an issue or not.

Any idea how I can fix this error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't need the node_modules in the path.

Comment: @mkaatman That's the folder it's in though. If I leave it out, the browser tells me it can't find it.

Comment: Are you using webpack? Webpack will compile everything into a minified bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Just clean cache and cookies. Then forces refresh. That solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not starting the application like you should (double-clicking on the `index.html` file?)

If you used react-scripts in order to create the app (like you probably should if you're a beginner), then use `npm run start` which will **compile** the code and the imports into one JavaScript bundle file and start a web page on http://localhost:3000

This will allow regular imports to work properly:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

And when deploying to a remote web server, use `npm run build` and copy the content of the `build` folder to the server.

Comment: How are you supposed to build a whole project if you can only host one page(on localhost no less) at a time? I can't even use localhost because I'm ssh'ing onto a uni server.

Answer (score 0):

most likely scenario here is it can't find the script file so the script fetch is returning a 404 which would be a text page saying it cant find it.

Double check the location in the index.html is what it should be

Comment: https://gyazo.com/8676d951c98a09ff3734dc424720baaa The path is correct but when I open it in the browser, the server returns this. So I'm guessing it's reading that when I try to import React. Should I add "index.js" to the import path or something?

Comment: You forgot to build the app, deploying a React app is not just copying source files on the web server. This is explained in my answer

Comment: thats a lovely screenshot but it doesnt tell me much. Try going to the network tab in your browsers dev tools and seeing what it actually fetches and the status of the fetch