# Code splitting not working with parcel in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, parceljs

I have this component which is from parcel's documentation. It said it should work by default.

```js
import React from 'react';

const Router = () => {
 ...
  const ComponentToRender = React.lazy(() => import(`./Pages/${variableCompoentName}/index.js`));
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <ComponentToRender />
    </React.Suspense>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

But I get an error in the browser saying:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

2src.7ed060e2.js:1362 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:1234/Pages/Home/index.js
```

What is the way around this? and what am I doing wrong?

here is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
    "react": "^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
     ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel public/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build public/index.html",
  }
```

**Update 1 December 2023**

Turns out I get the error because I am using a variable(`variableCompoentName`) inside import(`./Pages/${variableCompoentName}/index.js`)). because the names were generated at runtime, so they are never compiled.

Now my question is how do I ensure that they always get compiled? How do I go around this issue?

Comment: The update sounds like perhaps the issue is in some code that is not included in your question. Could you please update your question to include the relevant code. It seems likely that the dynamic import is where you're likely experiencing the issue and not in the component definition itself.

Comment: @Souperman If I replace the variable `${variableCompoentName}` with a plain string like `Home` it works. So I believe I have shared all the code I have to share.

Comment: I guess the point I’m trying to make is that the issue you’re seeing has to do with the dynamic import statement (and probably more generally with how parcel renames files during the compile phase) and not much to do with the actual content of your file containing the component definition. Your question, however, puts the component specification front and center with the relevant code relegated to the center of your final paragraph without any of the context surrounding it.

Comment: I guess I’m suggesting that instead of the component specification, it might be more illustrative to just show the two lines you’re describing. One with the literal “Home” string showing how that works and another line with your template string that doesn’t work so that future people with this problem can see exactly what works and what doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

As [guerric-p](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3738171/guerric-p) suggest in [Why does the server return MIME type of 'text/html' when I import React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146486/why-does-the-server-return-mime-type-of-text-html-when-i-import-react)

That could be cause you are need also ReactDOM

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

I'm not used to react but when u use file .js im think you should qoute your components / html

Instead of

```
return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <ComponentToRender />
    </React.Suspense>
  );
```

Do something like

```
return "<React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}><ComponentToRender /></React.Suspense>";
```

Or

```
return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={"<div>Loading...</div>"}>
      <ComponentToRender />
    </React.Suspense>
  );
```

And make sure on local enviroment like visual studio to run in terminal `npm run start`